# Having problem with rake devise:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to setup devise with putting `gem 'devise' , '1.1.2'` in gemfile and run `sudo bundle install` and then I try to run `rake --trace devise:setup`. Then the error come out , do anyone know what is wrong with my Rails 3 app?

```
(in /home/wizztjh/work/testing123)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'devise:setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1728:in `[]'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2050:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: by the way , can anyone teach me how to read documentation from github? such as site like https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you aren't using the appropriate way to install devise.  Here are the correct generators per the [devise documentation:](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.1.2/README.rdoc)

```
#this installs the devise initializer which is needed to run devise in r3. 
rails generate devise:install

#this generates your model as a devise resource
rails generate devise [MODEL_NAME]

#this copies all the view files into your local app for modifications
rails generate devise:views
```